# How to filter for Records in the admin backend

Tags: django

```
class OrderSVO(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)



class OrderSVOAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        """Limit Pages to those that belong to the request's user."""
        qs = super(OrderSVOAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            # It is mine, all mine. Just return everything.
            return qs
        # Now we just add an extra filter on the queryset and
        # we're done. Assumption: Page.owner is a foreignkey
        # to a User.
        return qs.filter(seller='A Seller Name')


admin.site.register(OrderSVO,OrderSVOAdmin)
```

I want to filter records in the backend for a specific seller

Answer (score 0):

Use a search field

```
class OrderSVOAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['seller',]
```

Comment: I want restricted seller records only for a specific seller

Comment: @sly_Chandan can you give more context? Is the seller the user accessing? B/c when you say filter, I imagine user can have some power